# How can i load image form directory to pictureBox delete the image file after loaded to picturebox and again to next images?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

```
int countimages = 0;
        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {           
            Image img = sc.CaptureWindowToMemory(windowHandle);
            Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(img,img.Width,img.Height);
            bmp.Save(@"e:\screenshotsofpicturebox1\screenshot" + countimages + ".bmp");
            bmp.Dispose();

            string[] images = Directory.GetFiles(@"e:\screenshotsofpicturebox1\", "*.bmp");
            if (images.Length > 0)
            {
                if (pictureBox1.Image != null)
                {
                    File.Delete(images[0]);
                    countimages = 0;
                    pictureBox1.Image.Dispose();
                }
                pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(images[countimages]);
            }
            countimages += 1;
            label1.Text = countimages.ToString();
        }
```

1. I want to save image to the hard disk
2. load the image to the pictureBox1
3. after the image loaded to pictureBox1 delete the file from the hard disk
4. save a new image to the hard disk and load it to the pictureBox1
5. delete the file and so on each time with a new image.

The problem for now is i'm getting exception on the line:

```
File.Delete(images[0]);
```

The process cannot access the file `e:\screenshotsofpicturebox1\screenshot0.bmp` because it is being used by another process.

Another problem I saw now it's saving each time a new file to the hard  disk

```
screenshot0.bmp
screenshot1.bmp
```

But I wan to be only one file each time `screenshot0.bmp` and just to replace it each time with a new image.

Comment: well the picture is open in the picture box so it makes sense you can not delete it right..? Same reason that if you open a picture in a photo viewer and then try to delete it you get an error message about how it can't be deleted because it is open in another process.

Comment: Why would you even want to save it and delete it from the hard disk when you can simply avoid it all together and just show it in the picture box?

Answer (score 0):

Reading your code I assume you are trying to show the screen in the picturebox on each tick event.
So, if that is your objective, you don't need to save/delete it, just assign the Image object to the PictureBox Image property like this:

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    Image refToDispose = pictureBox1.Image;
    pictureBox1.Image = sc.CaptureWindowToMemory(windowHandle);
    refToDispose.Dispose();
}
```

If you want to save/delete it anyway, you can't pass a directly loaded bitmap from the file to the PictureBox because it will lock the file while in use.

Instead you can create a graphics object from another Bitmap instance with the size of the image and draw it, so the new Bitmap will be a copy without the file lock that you can assign to the PictureBox.

In your code change this:

```
pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(images[countimages]);
```

To this:

```
using (Image imgFromFile = Image.FromFile(images[countimages])) {
    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(imgFromFile.Width, imgFromFile.Height);
    using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)) {
        g.DrawImage(imgFromFile, new Point(0, 0));
    }
    pictureBox1.Image = bmp;
}
```